# web2py doesn't display anything on google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web2py

I'm following the tutorials from Chapter 3 of the web2py book which work well locally in the admin interface.  I am now trying to deploy to GAE

I'm using a Mac and the deployment chapter of the book http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/13?search=gae#Deploying-on-Google-App-Engine reference 3 files:

```
web2py/app.yaml
web2py/queue.yaml
web2py/index.yaml
```

Are these files supposed to be in web2py/web2py.app/Contents/Resources?  I'm guessing the docs are out of date?

Also, app.yaml is configured to use the 'welcome' application.  I did a find and replace all to change 'welcome' to 'myapp' but upon launching dev_appserver.py from the web2py/web2py.app/Contents/Resources folder and navigating to localhost:8080 I get absolutely nothing

Answer (score 0):

No, you shouldn't be doing anything at all inside an .app. That's a bundle to make it easier to install things on a Mac: you need to create a directory for your project - probably somewhere inside your home directory - and do your development there.